# Why deeplearning4j regression example doesn't apply normalization for summing?

Tags: java, neural-network, deeplearning4j

While debugging regression [sample](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/feedforward/regression/RegressionSum.java) of deeplearning4j I've noticed that it doesn't have normalization of data inputs and outputs. So first of all question, why it doesn't have normalization? And second question, is there somewhere in network architecture normalization mechanism?

As prof of non-normalized input is the following screenshot which was taken right before execution of line

```
return new ListDataSetIterator(listDs,batchSize);
```

[image]

Comment: (1) As your image is showing only partial data, it's not proof for saying the data is not normalized (although statistically speaking it might give some hints) (2) Without analyzing the code, the most important part is this comment: ```// The range of the sample data, data in range (0-1 is sensitive for NN, you can try other ranges and see how it effects the results```.

Comment: I just created a pull request with data normalization for this example:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/pull/699

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We actually do normalization. We just don't do it for you automatically. It's right in our examples:

https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/convolution/AnimalsClassification.java#L115

All of our image classifiation examples do this. It's also documented on our website: https://deeplearning4j.org/image-data-pipeline.html We even have videos of this.

Edit: You can also normalize the labels if you want using the same DataNormalization api calling fitLabels(true) before you put data in to the neural network.

If you don't mind could you give me feedback as to how you couldn't find this so we can improve the website? I'm not sure what was missing here.

Comment: Looks like there is misunderstanding between us. I've asked about lack of normalization in file RegressionSum.java, but in your answer is mentioned AnimalClassification.java. AnimalClassification.java uses class  DataNormalization, but I didn't find any of normalizer class in RegressionSum.java. RegressionSum.java doesn't have DataNormalization, nor ImagePreProcessingScaler, nor anything else. And my question is why it doesn't have?

Comment: Ahh you mean in the example specifically - my apologies. I thought you were asking if dl4j had normalization in it. You don't always need normalization when you are tuning. A lot of normalization  can be bad for smal problems - it highly varies on the problem itself. Anything you see us doing is lots of empirical testing of the results to see what works. If you see something that improves the results feel free to send us a pull request.